# Examples of nilpotent subgroups of $S_n$ which have less than say 10^9 elements?

Tags: group-theory, permutations, finite-groups, nilpotent-groups

To make some computational experiments with finite nilpotent group - it would be helpful to know the following:

**Question:** What are the examples of nilpotent (but not commutative) subgroups in symmetric group $S_n$ which are not so big - say less than $10^9$ elements ?

Preferably given by explicit generators (permutations).

Comment: Sylow subgroups of symmetric groups, or other permutation groups? You could take direct products of these to get non$p$-groups.

Comment: @DerekHolt Thank you ! Are there explicit generators for Sylow subgroups ? (beyond S_p where they are cyclic  ) PS products - not what I need - that  are too simple. Sorry for not mentioning it in the question .

Comment: Yes there are explicit generators. Since you are talking about computer experiments, I was assuming that you would be familiar with GAP or Magma. They include functions that return the subgroups with generators.

Comment: I would prefer explicit permutations, since GAP seems cannot compute growth, but thank you any way !

Comment: Are you asking for (a) nilpotent groups of order $\leq 10^9$ or (b) nilpotent groups that embed in $S_n$, $|S_n| < 10^9$, i.e., nilpotent groups that have a faithful permutation representation on at most $12$ letters?

Comment: @TravisWillse (a)

Answer (score 1):

The smallest non-abelian nilpotent group is the dihedral group of order 8 the symmetries of a square. This can be realized as a permutation group by keeping track of what a square symmetry does to vertices. Then a rotation acts on vertices by cycling them: $(1 \; 2\; 3 \; 4)$ and a reflection acts by $(1 \; 2)(3 \; 4)$. These generate a copy of $D_4$ in $S_4$.

If you want to do computations, here are two other sources of examples:

1. Group extensions: a group is nilpotent iff it is an iterated extension by abelian groups. If you're comfortable with semi-direct products, these can lend themselves well to computations.
2. Upper triangular matrices with 1s on the diagonal. In particular, the [Heisenberg group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg_group). These groups lend themselves well to computations, and give good intuition about what nilpotent groups ``actually" are when you think about how they act on a vector space.

Comment: Thank you ! that I have considered already. I am interested in some other. up-triag of course main source - but soon running out of resources even on Z/2

Answer (score 1):

All $p$-groups, i.e., groups whose order is a prime power $p^m$, are nilpotent, so any nonabelian group of order such a power is an example (necessarily $m \geq 3$). Conversely, all finite nilpotent groups are direct products of groups of prime power orders.

So, the nilpotent, nonabelian groups of order $< 2^5$ are:

- Order 8

  - dihedral group, $D_8 \cong \langle (14)(23), (1234) \rangle$
  - quaternion group, $Q_8 \cong \langle (1247)(3685), (1348)(2576) \rangle$
- Order 16: all $9$ nonabelian groups
- Order 24: $C_3 \times D_8$, $C_3 \times Q_8$
- Order 27: $(C_3 \times C_3) \rightthreetimes C_3$, $C_9 \rightthreetimes C_3$

All of these groups can be realized as groups of permutations of $n \leq 12$ objects, except for [$Q_{16}$, the generalized quaternion group, which embeds in no symmetric group smaller than $S_{16}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4235415/155629).